# Rails 5 Puma server constantly freezes and hangs unless I set the worker count to 20

Tags: ruby-on-rails, concurrency, puma

I have a very tedious problem with Puma where the Rails server just hangs when receiving several concurrent HTTP requests. When I use 5 threads (Rails default) and 2 workers, the server freezes 90% of the time. If I set the worker count to 20 (which is obviously not ideal), then it only freezes about 5% of the time. But it freezes nonetheless. I am using Rails as an API for a separate Javascript app.

I have been debugging and Googling this relentlessly and have not found a fix. I notice that it happens exclusively when I load a page on the frontend that makes 6 concurrent POST "search" requests to 6 different Rails controllers. It seems like a concurrency issue, however, Rails should be able to handle 6 requests at once, right?

**To further explain my Rails setup:**

All of my controllers include the same module for all of their methods. I'm curious if Puma's concurrency is having issues using the same module for 6 different controllers at once, especially since they use the same instance variable to assign to each collection of search results. Could this be the issue? If so, a controller module seems to be a bad idea. What would be an alternative for a high order controller class/module that all controllers can use?

Comment: How long is each POST request? Could it be that these POST requests are heavy? How many database connections do you have in your pool? could your controllers be waiting for Database access for a long while?